# Find Power Series representation of the function $f(x) = {x\over 2x^2 + 1}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Find Power Series representation of the function $f(x) = \dfrac x{2x^2 + 1}$?

I'm not sure how to tackle this...I'm supposed to find interval of convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation: From the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\qquad\qquad\qquad |x|<1
\end{align*}

> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{x}{2x^2+1}&=\frac{x}{1-\left(-2x^2\right)}\\
> &=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2x^2)^n\qquad\qquad &|-2x^2|&<1\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2)^nx^{2n+1} &|x|&<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! This is how we we're taught in class. Awesome...

Comment: @Romaion: You're welcome! Good teacher! :-)

Answer (score 4):

$\sum x^n = \frac {1}{1-x}$ when $x$ is in the radius of convergence

$\sum (-x)^n = \frac {1}{1+x}\\
\sum (-x^2)^n =\sum (-1)^nx^{2n} =  \frac {1}{1+x^2}\\
\sum (-1)^n(\sqrt 2 x)^{2n} =\sum (-1)^n(2^n) x^{2n}  \frac {1}{1+2x^2}\\
x\sum (-1)^n(2^n)x^{2n} = \frac {x}{1+2x^2}\\
\sum (-1)^n(2^n)x^{2n+1} = \frac {x}{1+2x^2}$

The series conveges by the root test if:

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}|\sqrt[n]{a_n} x|<1$

$|\sqrt[n]{a_n}| = |2^{\frac {n}{2n+1}} x|<1$

$|x|<\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This method is a little different than what we've learned. We're supposed to try and transform f(x) into the form 1/(1-r), where |r| < 1, and then recognize that Sum (r^n)... That being said, I do follow how you've done it and thank you very much!

Comment: @Romaion Well, its the same way backwards, right?

Comment: Definitely similar...We're supposed to see x/(2x^2 + 1), pull out x => x (1/(2x^2 + 1)), and then find what r is which is where i screwed up to begin with lol.